# Show that a hyperplane $H$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is convex

Tags: solution-verification, convex-analysis

I'm reading a book that states the following definitions:

**Definition.** Let $\boldsymbol{c}$ be a given nonzero vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $k$ be a constant. A **hyperplance** $H$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the set

$$
H= \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n | \boldsymbol{c}^T\boldsymbol{x} = k \}
$$

**Definition.** A subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is called convex if for any two distinct points $\boldsymbol{x}_1$ and $\boldsymbol{x}_2$ in $S$ the line segment joining $\boldsymbol{x}_1$ and $\boldsymbol{x}_2$ lies in $S$. That is, $S$ is convex if whenever $\boldsymbol{x}_1$ and $\boldsymbol{x}_2$ $\in S$ so does
$$
\boldsymbol{x} = \lambda \boldsymbol{x}_1 + (1-\lambda) \boldsymbol{x}_2 \quad \text{for} \quad 0 \leq \lambda \leq 1
$$

In the exercises section, this question shows up

**Q:** Show that a hyperplane $H$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is convex.

My answer for this question as follows:

**Proof:** Let $\boldsymbol{x}_1,\boldsymbol{x}_2 \in H$, we need to show $\boldsymbol{x} \in H$ where
$$
\boldsymbol{x} = \lambda \boldsymbol{x}_1 + (1-\lambda)\boldsymbol{x}_2
$$

My understanding is that I need to show $\boldsymbol{c}^T\boldsymbol{x}$ equals to a constant; hence,

$$
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{c}^T\boldsymbol{x} 
&= \boldsymbol{c}^T\Big[ \lambda \boldsymbol{x}_1 + (1-\lambda)\boldsymbol{x}_2\Big],  \\
&= \lambda \boldsymbol{c}^T \boldsymbol{x}_1 + (1-\lambda)\boldsymbol{c}^T\boldsymbol{x}_2, \\
&= \lambda k_1 + (1-\lambda)k_2, \\
&= k_3. 
\end{align}
$$

Because $\boldsymbol{c}^T\boldsymbol{x} = k \implies \boldsymbol{x} \in H$, the hyperplane $H$ is a convex set.

Is this correct answer? If no, what needs to done to fix my proof?

---

**Edit:** the credit goes to @copper.hat in the comment section.
My modified answer is then

$$
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{c}^T\boldsymbol{x} 
&= \boldsymbol{c}^T\Big[ \lambda \boldsymbol{x}_1 + (1-\lambda)\boldsymbol{x}_2\Big],  \\
&= \lambda \boldsymbol{c}^T \boldsymbol{x}_1 + (1-\lambda)\boldsymbol{c}^T\boldsymbol{x}_2, \\
&= \lambda k + (1-\lambda)k, \\
&= \lambda k + k -\lambda k, \\
&= k. 
\end{align}
$$

Notice $\boldsymbol{x}_1,\boldsymbol{x}_2 \in H$ means $\boldsymbol{c}^T\boldsymbol{x}_1=\boldsymbol{c}^T\boldsymbol{x}_2=k$ and because $\boldsymbol{c}^T\boldsymbol{x} = k \implies \boldsymbol{x} \in H$, the hyperplane $H$ is a convex set.

Comment: This is not correct, you need to show that $c^T x = k$, not $k_3$. $k$ is an important part of defining the hyperplane. The fix is easy, since $c^T x_1 = k$ and similarly for $x_2$.

Comment: @copper.hat thank you for the swift comment. By $k_3$ I mean a mere constant. How this drastically changed the final result?

Comment: You need to show that $c^T x = k$ not any other constant. Every point satisfies $c^T x = y$ for some $y$.

Comment: @copper.hat, now I see your point. For example, if the hyperplane is a line, $k$ must be equal for the points $\boldsymbol{x}_1,\boldsymbol{x}_2$ and $\boldsymbol{x}$. In my proof, I misused this notation by introducing three constants (i.e. not necessarily equal) which drastically changed the answer.

Comment: You have that $c^Tx_1=k$ and $c^Tx_2=k$ and need to show that $\lambda c^Tx_1 + (1-\lambda )c^Tx_2 =k$.

Comment: @copper.hat if you wish, you can turn your valuable comment into an answer. Thank you.

Comment: @CroCo no need thanks, glad to be able to help.